# Videos, can't play after updating video card (AMD radeon)

Tags: drivers, graphics, video, radeon

After updating video cards in my ubuntu, No videos can't play, when I am trying to launch, it returns that output

```
vlc Movie\ HD.mp4 
VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6332)
[00005648b24e8570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
: CommandLine Error: Option 'help-list' registered more than once!
LLVM ERROR: inconsistency in registered CommandLine options
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

There is an output of

```
lspci -v -s `lspci | awk '/VGA/{print $1}'`
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Vega [Radeon Vega 8 Mobile] (rev c5) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Vega [Radeon Vega 8 Mobile]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
I/O ports at 1000 [size=256]
Memory at e0600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Comment: try to install the libva library: sudo apt install libva-drm1 libva1

Comment: The libva1 is on Ubuntu 16.04, on Ubuntu 18.04 the package name might be another: Use search: apt-cache search libva